# Laravel : Change data after update Request

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Select2 for create multiple data in database.

My Languages Field In Database:

```
English,French,Spanish
```

My Controller

```
public function store(UserCreateRequest $request)
  {

    $data = $request->all();
    $data['languages'] = implode(',', $request['languages']);
    User::create($data);
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Account Successfully Created');
  }
```

But After Update The language field changes as follows

```
["English","French","Spanish"]
```

Update in controller

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Account Successfully Updated');

}
```

I'm Using in_array() in edit Form For Showing Selected Data

Comment: Most probably you are sending languages as data in update form as well. Similar to create, you need to treat the language array in update as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create one methods, or rewrite you'r update methods

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    
    $data = $request->all();
    $data['languages'] = implode(',', $request['languages']);

    $user->update($data);
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Account Successfully Updated');

}
```

But I think batter create relation user -> manyToMany -> language, table example

```
user {user_id, email, password}
user_language {user_language_id, user_id, language_id}
language {language_id, key, title}
```

For select get all from language.
For attach language to user use attach method. For get all language just call `->languages` on user. And etc. Sorry for my English I hope you understand me.